# Manga where a non-human character (a robot?) has amnesia and saves another character from other giant robots

Tags: story-identification, manga

Years ago, back when I was in high school, I remember reading a manga in my school library and at the end of one of the books, you got a preview of another manga unrelated to the book. What I vaguely remember about it is that there was a non-human character (a robot I think?) in full white. He looked kinda like Shigeo from *Mob Psycho 100* whenever he goes into that "???" state except he was all white instead of black with crazy hair.

The story starts off with this machine seemingly having amnesia. He doesn't remember who he is or what he's doing there. But the few people there who spot him run for their lives as if he was a murder machine. Yet he saves a small creature (a child maybe?) from what is a giant robot that seems to think he's a traitor or malfunctioning. That's all I can remember. I know the style seemed simplistic and the protagonist was really powerful fighting giant robots right out of the gate.

I should also add that the robot character is not giant like the other robots he fights. just a very powerful small human sized one. It's also implied by the people running away from him that he might have been a destroyer before he lost his memory. Kind of similar to the iron giant. I'm not sure if this became an ongoing series or was just a one-shot that might have failed to get into the mainstream. But I feel it might have been the latter since the only thing I ever saw of it was the interesting premise. Again he looked similar to Mob in his other form but since the manga was black n white I only know he was a light color, so likely white.
https://external-preview.redd.it/_aOXCAkiWpohBj8NcmqJTKs8s64HnXiT3icBT0lIiqw.png?auto=webp&s=c76c44140d0bc84af3f81a40180382b0da661ea9
https://64.media.tumblr.com/6c6d2163205f3e90a55ee35f7179eeee/tumblr_inline_plv7sq1Cs61r0vc40_1280.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/77/ff/0677fff2eabf59ba14a0cd2fb397f696.gif

Comment: Do you remember what manga you were reading where you saw this preview?

Comment: There were multiple ones I read at that library. Things like one piece, naruto, bleach, Inuyasha and a few other ones that seemed more obscure. Like ones about characters in video game VR settings (It wasn't sword art online, so you can mark that one off the list) . However if I had to take my best guess, it might have been when I was reading Buso Renkin. Can't say for sure but that's one of my better memories in regards to what I was reading.

Comment: When were you in high school?

Comment: I'm currently 25. So around a decade ago.

Comment: https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tags/amnesia, one of these, perhaps?

Comment: I don't see it anywhere in that link. Most of those looked romance related, when I can safely say that's not what the genre of the manga I am looking for. Like I said, the robot has an appearance that's similar (but not identical) to this
https://external-preview.redd.it/_aOXCAkiWpohBj8NcmqJTKs8s64HnXiT3icBT0lIiqw.png?auto=webp&s=c76c44140d0bc84af3f81a40180382b0da661ea9
https://66.media.tumblr.com/6c6d2163205f3e90a55ee35f7179eeee/tumblr_inline_plv7sq1Cs61r0vc40_1280.jpg
https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/77/ff/0677fff2eabf59ba14a0cd2fb397f696.gif

Comment: How certain are you that this is a preview of another manga, and not a side/bonus story to what you were reading? I've never seen a long preview at the end of a manga volume before, only full page adverts.

Comment: Very. The style was to different to compare to most other manga I read at the time, if it was a bonus, it certainly was unrelated to the universe that manga took place in.

Answer (score 1):

I got you. I am pretty sure you are talking about Casshern Sins. This was actually an anime that later got a manga adaption and was originally adapted from an older animated series. Casshern, a cyborg who lost his memories, saves a robotic dog, and they travel a destroyed world helping people.  [anilist](https://anilist.co/anime/4981/Casshern-Sins):

> In the distant future, where cyborgs and humans struggle to survive after the war which destroyed the world, a being in white suit awakens. His name is Casshern and he remembers nothing of his own past.
>
> In barren and dark dystopian world, where every being alive seems to hate his existence and the evil from his past wants him dead, Casshern, haunted by the flashes of his past memories has to survive and figure out who or what exactly he is and how he got to where he is now. But he does not know that he might not like the horrible truth of the past, hidden deep inside his mind...
>
> Created as an intended reboot of Casshern franchise.